# Virtual IP address on RedHat 6

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface

I have server (A) running with a static IP address (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) in my company. I need to assign virtual IP address to this Server (A). My production team expects script file where they can execute to up / down VIP (Virtual IP). I tried googling but end with [Create Virtual IP](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3434), I don't have access. Looking for expert advice on, how to create and assign Virtual IP address to existing server?

Note : Currently we have one prod server and one DR server. We may be scaling it  up in future.

Environment : Redhat 6

Comment: Did you use google? https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rhel+virtual+IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for an alias.

assuming your IP on eth0 is 192.168.230.128, you can have an alias either by

- setting ifcfg-eth0:1 (/etc/sysconfig/network-script)

  ```
  DEVICE="eth0:1"
  BOOTPROTO="static"
  IPADDR=192.168.230.253
  NETWORK=192.168.230.0
  NETMASK=255.255.255.0
  IPV6INIT="yes"
  NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
  ONBOOT="yes"
  ```
- or at run time

  ```
  ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.230.253/24 up
  ```

former method will work from boot, latter at run time only (and will be lost on reboot).